# woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value filter making my meta_value to null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am manipulating `$meta_value` from my custom plugin by adding my custom image variable through `wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'custom_img_thumb',$custom_img_thumb_nail);`  and it is saving in table as well.But, my problem is  `$custom_img_thumb_nail` is an image(`<img src='localhost/../../img.png'/>`) by this `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_value', $meta_value )` filter my $meta_value is becoming blank. my output is coming like 
`Array(
    [label] => Custom_img_thumb
    [value] => 
)`
Instead

```
Array(
[label] => Custom_img_thumb
[value] => <img src='localhost/../../img.png'/>)
```

Updated:
This is my actual code for inserting meta to a table.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_order_item_meta','mc_custom_add_order_item_meta',1,2);
function mc_custom_add_order_item_meta($item_id, $values){
    global $woocommerce,$wpdb;

    $custom_img_thumb = $values['custom_img_thumb'];
    if(!empty($custom_img_thumb))
    {

        $custom_img_thumb_nail =$custom_img_thumb;//('<img src='localhost/../../img.png'/>')
        wc_add_order_item_meta($item_id,'custom_img_thumb',$custom_img_thumb_nail);

    }
}
```

But displaying making problem.

Comment: How did you get `$meta_value` ? More code required to debug this.

Comment: Hi Rohil,Please see my updated code.Meta value I traced its coming from class-wc-order-item-meta.php file